# Отсутствует шаблон для WPF4 в MVVM Light

Tags: c#, mvvm

скачал и установил MVVM Light V5.2.0

Мне нужен оттуда именно шаблон и все плюшечки для работы с WPF4 (FW 4.0), но его нет. Где его можно взять?

Comment: http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/ - оффсайт грит что должно быть в коробке.

Comment: @Monk, видимо в коробке для 2012 и 13 студий (именно на их примере показана инсталляция). :(